# Interpreting "condition has length > 1" warning from `if` function

Tags: r, if-statement

I have an array:

```
a <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

and would like to implement the following function:

```
w<-function(a){
  if (a>0){
    a/sum(a)
  }
  else 1
}
```

This function would like to check whether there is any value in `a` larger than 0 and if yes then divide each element by the sum of the total.

Otherwise it should just record 1.

I get the following warning message:

```
 Warning message:
 In if (a > 0) { :
 the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

How can I correct the function?

Comment: @user1723765 what do you expect to have as a result?

Comment: so basically if a a[a>0] then a/sum(a) should be done, not a[a>0]/sum(a)

Comment: the result would be 0s and .166667 etc for the other numbers but I would still have the entire vector in the end

Comment: yes I just realized. thanks!

Comment: Does your actual vector contain zeroes and ones only?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

maybe you want `ifelse`:

```
a <- c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,2,2)
ifelse(a>0,a/sum(a),1)

 [1] 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 1.000 1.000 1.000 1.000
 [9] 0.250 0.250
```

Comment: Warning: ifelse only uses as many elements from your solution, as there are elements in the condition! It does NOT warn about this. For example `ifelse(TRUE, 1:5, 5:1)` returns `1` as answer and not `1:5`. ifelse(c(T, T), 1:5, 5:1)` returns `c(1, 2)`, etc. Use with caution.

Answer (score 58):

`if` statement is not vectorized. For vectorized if statements you should use `ifelse`. In your case it is sufficient to write

```
w <- function(a){
if (any(a>0)){
  a/sum(a)
}
  else 1
}
```

or a short vectorised version

```
ifelse(a > 0, a/sum(a), 1)
```

It depends on which do you want to use, because first function gives output vector of length 1 (in else part) and `ifelse` gives output vector of length equal to length of `a`.

Comment: why oh why, if everything else in R-land is vectorized...'if' isn't? Smdh.

Comment: Your solution with if(any()) helped me 9 years after. You're a genius. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

Just adding a point to the whole discussion as to why this warning comes up (It wasn't clear to me before). The reason one gets this is as mentioned before is because 'a' in this case is a vector and the inequality 'a>0' produces another vector of TRUE and FALSE (where 'a' is >0 or not).

If you would like to instead test if any value of 'a>0', you can use functions - 'any' or 'all'

Best

Answer (score 21):

Here's an easy way without `ifelse`:

```
(a/sum(a))^(a>0)
```

An example:

```
a <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)

(a/sum(a))^(a>0)

[1] 1.00 0.25 1.00 1.00 0.25 0.25 1.00 0.25
```

Comment: This beats `ifelse` by about a factor of 7 (on a 100000 element array).

Comment: Could you recommend a succinct explanation/documentation of this `^` operator (e.g., what it's called and how it works). Preferably something more straightforward than the [Arithmetic Operators](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Arithmetic.html) documentation...

Comment: @theforestecologist The operator `^` is used for exponentiation. The command `x  ^ y` means: `x` raised to the power of `y`. The code `2 ^ 3` will compute `2 * 2 * 2`.

Answer (score 2):

The way I cam across this question was when I tried doing something similar where I was defining a function and it was being called with the array like others pointed out

You could do something like this however for this scenarios its less elegant compared to Sven's method.

```
sapply(a, function(x) afunc(x))

afunc<-function(a){
  if (a>0){
    a/sum(a)
  }
  else 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `lapply` function after creating your function normally.

```
lapply(x="your input", fun="insert your function name")
```

`lapply` gives a list so use `unlist` function to take them out of the function

```
unlist(lapply(a,w))
```

Comment: Do you mean `unlist` takes it out of the list, not function?

Comment: yeah i meant that , sorry for mistype

Answer (score 1):

I would say the most efficient way is the answer by
user1317221_G. However, if you want to go back to the basics, then looping over the length of your vector (since the if function doesnt work over the length of the vector) using the for function would be useful.

```
w <- c() ##creates empty vector named 'w'
for(i in 1:length(a)){
  if (a[i]>0){
    w[i] <- a[i]/sum(a)
  }
  else 
    w[i] <- 1
}
```