# How can I flag outliers using an ifelse statement?

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I am trying to write my first function and ifelse statement to identify outliers in one column of a dataframe. I first created a new column in which outliers should be flagged `(dat$outliers = NULL)` and then wrote my function

```
outliers<-function(x){
  for (Column1 in x) { 
    if (Column1  < 90) {
      1
    } else if (Column1  > 130){
  1
    } else 
      0
  }
}
```

However, I get the following error:

> Error in if (Column1 < 90) { :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE
>   needed In addition: Warning messages: 1: In if (Column1 < 90) { :
>   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be
>   used

I realise that this is probably a very clunky way of approaching the problem in the first place, but having almost no experience in programming I am struggling to make sense of reference material online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if` and `else` take scalar [logical](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/Logic) values.  [`ifelse`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/ifelse) does vectorised logical comparison, though in this case you don't really need it.

```
is_outlier <- function(x) {
  x < 90 | x > 130
}
```

Note that your function now returns a logical vector rather than one or zero.

I renamed your function to start with `is` (it is customary for functions that return a logical value to begin with "is" or "has".)

---

Further reading on the error and warning:

[Error In R: Missing Value where TRUE/FALSE needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355187/error-in-r-missing-value-where-true-false-needed)

[Interpreting "condition has length > 1" warning from `if` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170778/interpreting-condition-has-length-1-warning-from-if-function)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the further reading material, very helpful.

Comment: True, but hardly worthy of creating a function :-)

Answer (score 2):

Simply

```
is.outlier <- (x<90 | x>130)  #returns vector of TRUE/FALSE
```

Or if all you need is the indices,

```
outliers <- which(x<90 | x>130)
```