# change the weekend date to weekday date in R

Tags: r, date, if-statement

I am reading in an excel file in R and calculating the date 6 months prior to the date. If the date is falls on Weekend, need to change the date to the following weekday.

for example: if date is 2020-2-7, the six months prior is 2019-08-11. Which is Sunday.
How do I change the date to 2019-08-12?

I tried the following code:

```
date <- as.date.character("2020-2-7")
nxtd <- date-180
if(weekdays(nxtd)=="Saturday"){nxtd <- date-182} else if(weekdays(nxtd)=="Sunday"){nxtd <- date-181}
else{nxtd <- date-180}
```

this code gives an error/warning " the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

How do I resolve it?

Comment: If you want to check that a value is in a vector, you can use `%in%`. `==` checks that two things are equal. `if / else` structures in R aren't vectorized, which is why you get the warning (not error)—the condition will only be checked against the first value. Use the vectorized `ifelse`. In this case, doesn't really matter since your example has only 1 value, but I imagine your real data has more. You're also missing 2 closing quotation marks.

Comment: My real data has about 50 rows of data.

Comment: That's what I figured, which is why you'll want to switch to `ifelse`. That warning is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14170778/5325862). Also, you're assuming 6 months is exactly 180 days—is that really what you want?

Comment: @camille, thanks, yea, I need to stick with 180 days.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(lubridate)
d1 = as.Date("2020-2-9")
d2 = d1 - 180
if(weekdays(d2) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday")){
    floor_date(d2 - 3, "week") + 8
} else {
    d2
}
```

Comment: This will only work when you have a single date, when you have multiple dates, the error of "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used" remains.

Comment: Could you explain the subtract 3 and add 8 operations?