# Access column using variable name in R in if statement, condition has length > 1

Tags: r, dataframe

How could I identify a column in R dataframe using a variable? In the following code, I used `paste0` to identify a columns with variable. Is there any alternative?

```
if ((leadsnp4[[paste0('Z_in_',trait1)]] > 0) & (leadsnp4[[paste0('Z_in_',trait2)]] > 0))
{leadsnp4$ConcordEffect='Yes'} else if ((leadsnp4[[paste0('Z_in_',trait1)]] < 0) & (leadsnp4[[paste0('Z_in_',trait2)]] < 0))
{leadsnp4$ConcordEffect='Yes'} else if ((leadsnp4[[paste0('Z_in_',trait1)]] > 0) & (leadsnp4[[paste0('Z_in_',trait2)]] < 0))
{leadsnp4$ConcordEffect='No'} else if ((leadsnp4[[paste0('Z_in_',trait1)]] < 0) & (leadsnp4[[paste0('Z_in_',trait2)]] > 0))
{leadsnp4$ConcordEffect='No'}
```

leadsnp4 is a dataframe. `trait1` and `trait2` are user defined variables. The above code is giving me warning : `The condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`. Also not getting the expected output.
Not sure what is wrong here. Maybe there are other alternatives for the above `if else` statements. Any help?

Comment: what are `trait1` and `traint2`? can you post some data using `dput`?

Comment: This question is related to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170778/interpreting-condition-has-length-1-warning-from-if-function

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're selecting columns in fine. Using `df[[col_name]]` (list context) is the same as `df[, col_name]` -- each returns a vector copy of column `col_name`. You can save the column name as a variable instead of using `paste0` directly in the selection.

The reason you're getting an error is that `if` is not vectorized and you're giving it a vector with length > 1. In this case, `if` uses only the first value in the vector, but warns that it's doing so. `ifelse` is the vectorized version in base R (there's also `dplyr::if_else`). If I understand your code, the below should be close to what you're looking for.

```
t1 <- paste0('Z_in_', trait1)
t2 <- paste0('Z_in_', trait2)

# a single boolean vector indicating if trait1 and trait2 are 
# both positive or both negative
same_sign <- ((leadsnp4[, t1] > 0) & (leadsnp4[, t2] > 0)) | 
  ((leadsnp4[, t1] < 0) & (leadsnp4[, t2] < 0))

leadsnp4$ConcordEffect <- ifelse(same_sign, "Yes", "No")
```

Note that if `trait1` and/or `trai2` are equal to 0 they will be assigned `false`. You'll need to modify the logic if this is not the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explanation for why pasting will not work for creating a column reference and one suggestion for what you can do instead: [Dynamically select data frame columns using $ and a character value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/dynamically-select-data-frame-columns-using-and-a-character-value)