If ... else : the condition has length > 1
I am trying to classify variants according to their type (polymorphisms, insertion or deletion). Here is a snippet of my input :
A  T
G  C
T  AG
C  T
TT C
AT CC

Here is the dput output, if you need it :
df = class(structure(c("A", "G", "T", "C", "TT", "AT", "T", "C", "AG", "T", "C", "CC"), dim = c(6L, 2L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("REF", "ALT")))

I want variants classified as :

SNP when ALT length = REF length = 1,
MNV when ALT length = REF length,
deletion when ALT length < REF length,
and insertion when REF length > ALT length.

The output should be something like this :
A  T   SNV
G  C   SNV
T  AG  Insertion
C  T   SNV
TT C   Deletion
AT CC  MNV

I have tried this :
variants = data.frame(
  REF = file@fix[, 4],
  ALT = file@fix[, 5],
  VARIANTTYPE =
    if (nchar(file@fix[, 4]) == nchar(file@fix[, 5]))
      {ifelse(nchar(file@fix[, 4]) == 1 & nchar(file@fix[, 5]) == 1, "Single nucleotide variant", "Multinucleotide variant")}
    else if (nchar(file@fix[, 4]) < nchar(file@fix[, 5])) {"Insertion"}
    else if (nchar(file@fix[, 4]) > nchar(file@fix[, 5])) {"Deletion"}
  else {"nothing"})

But I get this error :
Error in if (nchar(file@fix[, 4]) == nchar(file@fix[, 5])) { : 
  the condition has length > 1

The only solution I have found on the internet to fix it is to use ifelse, but ifelse only accepts one condition, and I wouldn't be able to classify all variants at once.
Do you have any idea ? Thank you for your help !

You need the ifelse function, not the if ... else ... statement.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170778/interpreting-condition-has-length-1-warning-from-if-function

Here you find two solutions in the most common frameworks: tidyverse and data.table.

tidyverse
You could use case_when from the dplyr package.
Like this:
df <- structure(c("A", "G", "T", "C", "TT", "AT", "T", "C", "AG", "T", "C", "CC"), 
                dim = c(6L, 2L),
                dimnames = list(NULL, c("REF", "ALT")))


df <- as.data.frame(df)

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df |> 
  mutate(VARIANTTYPE = case_when(
    
    # SNP when ALT length = REF length = 1,
    str_length(ALT) == str_length(REF) & str_length(ALT) == 1 ~ "SNP",
    
    # MNV when ALT length = REF length,
    str_length(ALT) == str_length(REF) ~ "MNV",
    
    # deletion when ALT length < REF length,
    str_length(ALT) < str_length(REF) ~ "Deletion",
    
    # and insertion when ALT length > REF length.
    str_length(ALT) > str_length(REF) ~ "Insertion",
    
  ))
#>   REF ALT VARIANTTYPE
#> 1   A   T         SNP
#> 2   G   C         SNP
#> 3   T  AG   Insertion
#> 4   C   T         SNP
#> 5  TT   C    Deletion
#> 6  AT  CC         MNV

Created on 2024-07-22 with reprex v2.1.0

data.table
You could use fcase from the data.table package.
df <- structure(c("A", "G", "T", "C", "TT", "AT", "T", "C", "AG", "T", "C", "CC"), 
                dim = c(6L, 2L),
                dimnames = list(NULL, c("REF", "ALT")))


library(data.table)

df <- as.data.table(df)

df[,
   VARIANTTYPE := fcase(
     
     # SNP when ALT length = REF length = 1,
     nchar(ALT) == nchar(REF) & nchar(ALT) == 1, "SNP",
     
     # MNV when ALT length = REF length,
     nchar(ALT) == nchar(REF), "MNV",
     
     # deletion when ALT length < REF length,
     nchar(ALT) < nchar(REF), "Deletion",
     
     # and insertion when ALT length > REF length.
     nchar(ALT) > nchar(REF), "Insertion"
   )
]

df
#>       REF    ALT VARIANTTYPE
#>    <char> <char>      <char>
#> 1:      A      T         SNP
#> 2:      G      C         SNP
#> 3:      T     AG   Insertion
#> 4:      C      T         SNP
#> 5:     TT      C    Deletion
#> 6:     AT     CC         MNV

Created on 2024-07-22 with reprex v2.1.0

Using dplyr::case_when
library(dplyr)

nref <- nchar(mat[,"REF"])
nalt <- nchar(mat[,"ALT"])

cbind(mat, case_when(nref == nalt & nref == 1 ~ "SNP", 
                     nref == nalt & nref == 2 ~ "MNV", 
                     nref > nalt ~ "Insertion", 
                     nref < nalt ~ "Deletion",
                     .default = NA))
     REF  ALT
[1,] "A"  "T"  "SNP"
[2,] "G"  "C"  "SNP"
[3,] "T"  "AG" "Deletion"
[4,] "C"  "T"  "SNP"
[5,] "TT" "C"  "Insertion"
[6,] "AT" "CC" "MNV"

Data
mat <- structure(c("A", "G", "T", "C", "TT", "AT", "T", "C", "AG", "T",
"C", "CC"), dim = c(6L, 2L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("REF", "ALT"
)))


Before using R packages (tidyverse, dplyr, or data.table), it may help to know R. To do this, take off your C hat and put on your R hat. This is a job for vectors. Using the df you defined,
df <- structure(c("A", "G", "T", "C", "TT", "AT", "T", "C", "AG", "T", 
"C", "CC"), dim = c(6L, 2L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("REF", "ALT"
)))

initialize the output vector and assign slots based on comparisons.
VARIANTTYPE <- rep('nothing', 6)

Then assign each scenario
VARIANTTYPE[nchar(df[, 1]) == nchar(df[, 2]) & nchar(df[, 1]) == 1] <- 'SNP'
VARIANTTYPE[nchar(df[, 1]) == nchar(df[, 2]) & nchar(df[, 1]) > 1] <- 'MNP'
VARIANTTYPE[nchar(df[, 1]) < nchar(df[, 2]) ] <- 'deletion'
VARIANTTYPE[nchar(df[, 1]) > nchar(df[, 2]) ] <- 'insertion'


It works, thank you !!
